# git push - having to specify the path

Tags: git, github, push

Is there a way I can use "git push" without specifying the path back to my github repo?
*example:* **git@github.com:someuser/someproject.git**

I thought I had found the answer to this by using. **git push origin master**
But realized this afternoon that this wasn't actually pushing any code changes to my repo.
One of the people I'm collaborating with - doesn't have to specifiy the push location - why do I? I'm sure I just have something misconfigured. I'm the owner of the repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make an existing git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Answer (score 4):

yes. You specify that when you create a remote using `git remote add origin <some url>`. Then you can set the push command to always do that for certain branches.

```
git push -u origin somebranch
```

This will enable you to just

```
git push
```

from then on to push that branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Just couldn't figure out what I missed. And if I catch the intent here... you have the ability to send different branch code to different repo servers. Pretty slick +1 and answer